# Symfony redirection on remote server

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to put a Symfony project on a remote server. Everything works except any of the redirecting.

the directory structure looks like this

```
/var
    /www
        /myproject
            /app
            /src
            /bin
            /vendor
            /web
                app_dev.php
```

> www.website.org/myproject/web/app_dev.php/login

redirects to

> /myproject/web/app_dev.php/login_check

which doesn't exist. I want it to redirect to

> www.website.org/myproject/web/app_dev.php/login_check

Answer (score 0):

If you use generateUrl() inside the controller, you can generate an absolute URL by specifying the 3rd argument as UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL.

```
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;

$this->generateUrl('login_check',
                    array('arg1' => 'value1'),
                    UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL);
//(assuming route name for /login_check/ is 'login_check')
// http://www.example.com/app_dev.php/login_check
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html

On the other hand, if you would like to generate one in twig, simply you could call(2.7~)

```
{{ url('login_check', {'param': 'value'}) }}
```

Comment: I bieleve TWIG has **url()** function: `{{ url('blog_show', {'slug': 'my-blog-post'}) }}` At least as of 2.7: [http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/book/routing.html#generating-absolute-urls](http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/book/routing.html#generating-absolute-urls)

Comment: @lllypa  that is simpler. I will correct mine, thanks.